# Rails: Configure logger in production to work with Papertrail

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logging, heroku, papertrail-app

I'm trying to configure my logger to work in production on a Rails 5.1.4 app deployed to Heroku. I'm using Papertrail but my custom log messages are not being shown in there. I'm not getting any error. What's wrong?

My config/environments/production.rb:

```
if ENV["RAILS_LOG_TO_STDOUT"].present?
    logger           = ActiveSupport::Logger.new(STDOUT)
    logger.formatter = config.log_formatter
    config.logger    = ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(logger)
end
```

My Heroku variables:

```
RAILS_LOG_TO_STDOUT    enabled
RACK_ENV               production
RAILS_ENV              RAILS_ENV
```

In my methods, I've been trying to call the logger like this:

```
Rails.logger.info "Logger message..."
```

I have also tried to follow these steps: https://help.papertrailapp.com/kb/configuration/configuring-centralized-logging-from-ruby-on-rails-apps/#configure-rails-environment but it didn't work either. In this case I installed the gem remote_syslog_logger and changed my config/environments/production.rb code to:

```
if ENV["RAILS_LOG_TO_STDOUT"].present?
    logger           = ActiveSupport::Logger.new(STDOUT)
    logger.formatter = config.log_formatter
    config.logger    = RemoteSyslogLogger.new('my-app-name.papertrailapp.com', 5432)
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

Heroku forces logging to STDERR/STDOUT. Setting a custom logging destination won't have an effect in Heroku's environment. To get logs into Papertrail (or any other remote syslog server), you'll need to [set up a log drain](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/log-drains).